# Find and update item (in collection) in Redux store

Tags: redux

Given the collection:

`const peeps = [
     {name: 'John', id: 1},
     {name: 'Paul', id: 2},
     {name: 'George', id: 3},
    {name: 'Pete', id: 4}
  ];`

What is the recommended way to find the item with `id: 4` and update the name `Pete` to `Ringo` in a Redux store, with no mutations?

Edit: I know that changing the shape of the object (using an object with an ID key) would be better than an array, but I have no control over the shape of data and have to use the above shape.

Comment: @httpNick there are just tons of questions about updating element deep in a state tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to use the `.map()` method inside your reducer. Your action will include a payload of `id` which is the id of the `peep` to be updated, and a `newName` to use to update.

Your `peeps` state:

```js
const state = [
  {name: 'John', id: 1},
  {name: 'Paul', id: 2},
  {name: 'George', id: 3},
  {name: 'Pete', id: 4}
];
```

Your action creator will take an `id` and a `newName` argument and create an action with them:

```js
const updateName = (id, newName) => {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_NAME',
    payload: {
      id
      newName
    }
  };
};
```

You'd dispatch the action like:

```js
dispatch(updateName(4, 'Ringo'));
```

Your reducer will receive your action and use the `id` and `newName` provided to map through all the `peeps`, find the one that matches the given `id` and update its `name` to be equal to the `newName` passed in.

```js
const peeps = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_NAME':
      const { id, newName } = action.payload;

      // This returns a new array instead of mutating the old one
      return state.map(peep => {
        if (peep.id === id) {
          peep.name = newName;
        }
        return peep;
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```